# Trying to build a dynamic query string with node hapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

Hey I am building my first hapi api and I am connecting to a sql server database just fine but I am trying to build a dynamic query string based on what the client sends to me. so right now I am getting the different parameters from the query string just fine however sometimes they can be empty or not depending on what the user fills out is a more robust query that I send to the server. here is my code

```
  handler: (request, reply) => {
            const query = request.query;
            const quoteNum = request.query.QuoteNum;
            let numOfQuotes = request.query.NumOfQuotes;
            let filterType = request.query.Filter;
            const beginDate = request.query.StartDate;
            const endDate = request.query.EndDate;
            const optionsType = request.query.MoreOptionsType;
            const optionsQuery = request.query.moreOptionsQuery;
            const optionsValue = request.query.MoreOptionsString;
            switch (numOfQuotes) {
                case '100':
                    numOfQuotes = "SELECT TOP 100";
                    break;
                case '200':
                    numOfQuotes = "SELECT TOP 200";
                    break;
                case '500':
                    numOfQuotes = "SELECT TOP 500";
                    break;
                case '1000':
                    numOfQuotes = "SELECT TOP 1000";
                    break;
                case '2000':
                    numOfQuotes = "SELECT TOP 2000";
                    break;
                case '5000':
                    numOfQuotes = "SELECT TOP 5000";
                    break;
                case '10000':
                    numOfQuotes = "SELECT TOP 10000";
                    break;
                case 'ALL':
                    numOfQuotes = "SELECT";
                    break;
                default:
                    numOfQuotes = "SELECT TOP 50";
            }
            if (filterType != '') {
                switch (filterType) {
                    case 'Q':
                        filterType = " AND SOHeader.SOTypeID = 'Q'"
                        break;
                    case 'SO':
                        filterType = " AND SOHeader.SOTypeID = 'SO'"
                        break;
                    case 'TI':
                        filterType = " AND SOHeader.SOTypeID = 'TI'"
                        break;
                    case 'SO & TI':
                        filterType = " AND SOHeader.SOTypeID IN ('SO', 'TI')"
                        break;
                    case 'RPL':
                        filterType = " AND SOHeader.SOTypeID = 'RPL'"
                        break;
                    case 'RFC':
                        filterType = " AND SOHeader.SOTypeID = 'RFC'"
                        break;
                    case 'BT':
                        filterType = " AND SOHeader.SOTypeID = 'BT'"
                        break;
                    case 'CW':
                        filterType = " AND SOHeader.SOTypeID = 'CW'"
                        break;
                    case 'CWR':
                        filterType = " AND SOHeader.SOTypeID = 'CWR'"
                        break;
                    case 'CWR & BT & CW':
                        filterType = " AND SOHeader.SOTypeID IN ('CWR','BT','CW')"
                        break;
                }
            }
            conn.connect().then(() => {
                const req = new sql.Request(conn);
                let myBeginQuery = `${numOfQuotes} DISTINCT SOHeader.OrdNbr, soheader.sotypeid, soheader.user6, SOheader.LUpd_DateTime, SOHeader.User3, soheader.crtd_user, SOHeader.S4Future01, SOHeader.SlsperID, SOHeader.TotMerch, SOHeader.CustOrdNbr 
              FROM SOHeader 
              INNER JOIN Customer ON SOHeader.CustID = Customer.CustId 
              INNER JOIN SOLine ON SOHeader.OrdNbr = SOLine.OrdNbr
              WHERE soheader.CpnyID = 'AOS'
              and Customer.custid = @input_param`;
              let myQuery = '';
                if (filterType != '') {
                    myQuery = myBeginQuery + filterType;
                }
                console.log(myQuery);
```

when I console.log(myquery) it is still blank I think i need to promisfy it or something because the way javascript executes. Any suggestions would be helpful thanks

Answer (score 0):

From your code, the only way `myQuery` variable can be blank is if `filterType` variable is blank.

Make sure you're passing the right value in your query string for variable `Filter` by printing it to console

```
    console.log(request.query.Filter);
```

You do not need promises for this as you're printing the query string only.